# Not able to access rest API of external jar import to another spring boot app

Tags: rest, spring-boot, executable-jar

I have one application has Restful API which is working fine. I created a runnable Jar of that project and added as external lib for another spring boot project. But I am not able to access the API in jar file directly. I can access methods of jar file but not able to call API directly from the postman.

I am using Spring boot.

Comment: You have to be running the jar on a server, Spring Boot has a embeded server, but you need at least to run the jar so it listens to requests.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Need to add Jar for local repository using maven cmd
 i.e: mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= \
    -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=
and add the dependency in pom.xml so that jar will be running inside project u can access API inside the jar

BUT maybe some issues will come in the dependency version and conflict have to look at it.